# Multiplying different types in AVX512

Tags: c++, c, sse, avx, avx512

I am currently trying to multiply a `__m512d` value with a `__m512i` value. The `__m512d` value is ln(2), so the result is saved in another `__m512d` variable.
However, I am not able to find any intrinsics for multiplying a double with an integer in avx512.
When I use the `_mm512_castsi512_pd` intrinsic on the `__m512i`, I get a wrong value, so I guess that intrinsic is not of much help either.

I am glad for any help or workaround.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want convert, not cast.  SIMD casts just reinterpret the bit pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter Cordes for pointing out the mistake regarding the difference between casting and converting.
The following code allows the multiplication:

```
__m512d a;
__m512i b;
_mm512_muld_pd(a,_mm512_cvtepi64_pd(b));
```